# Word automation, reading table data with non-matching (split) row/columns

Tags: ms-word

(Hard because of split cells)
I'd like to be able to read Word table contents like I can in HTML (and still be able to tell which row and column they belong to).
Unfortunately Word makes this difficult, because you have to read it cell by cell and then compare width and height to find which column, row they belong to if you have split cells..

Is there a way to read Word table data through Word Automation programmatically, and be able to preserve what (visual) row and column they belong to?

Note: I'm doing this in C# right now, but any example I can easily port would be helpful.  I'm having a bad time trying to implement row/col width/height scanning.

Comment: not really, but you can get the HTML from the clipboard after copying the table (or just save the file as .html or .mhtml)

Comment: @Slai sorry to bother you for this, are you able to provide a sample of how I would copy the table as HTML?  I might just use that as a hack and do string/position compare to find positions of meta data I need

Comment: something like `table.Range.Copy(); var htmlFragment = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);` with `using System.Windows.Forms;`

Comment: @Slai it's kind of ridiculous that I have to use hacks like that or compare dimensions.  Surprised nobody wrote a library to do it.  Sigh, Microsoft, why? >:(  I mean if they could do it with HTML, why couldn't they just expose it as meta data or a function?

Comment: converting to HTML loses some of the layout information. For more details there is also `table.Range.XML` and `table.Range.WordOpenXML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program was kind of a hackish program anyways, and was only used as a helping source of data.  Someone else created another version (with its own set of problems).  Manual labor was opted for for the bulk of the work due to various reasons not related to this program, and the outputs of these programs was used as a side helper.
I opted for a mix of converting to HTML, using `table.Range.Copy()` `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html)`, and comparing dimensions, to do a best guess attempt that mostly worked.  I couldn't use XML or WordOpenXML due to the document format.
So thanks go out to Slai for that tip back then.